# Why is Flux.jl throwing a "Warning: Slow Fallback implementation" and DimensionMismatch?

Tags: julia, conv-neural-network, ijulia-notebook

I am trying to create a convolutional neural network to classify MNIST data with Flux in Julia. I downloaded the data as a csv from this link: https://www.kaggle.com/oddrationale/mnist-in-csv.
My code is below:

```
using CSV
using DataFrames
using Images
using Base.Iterators: partition
using Flux

sqrt(x) = convert(Int64, floor(x^0.5))
matrixize(x) = cat([x[i:i+sqrt(length(x))-1] for i in 1:sqrt(length(x)):length(x)]..., dims=2)'
img(x) = Gray.(x)
process(row) = img(matrixize(row[2:length(row)])), convert(Int, 255*row[1]) |> gpu

train_data = DataFrame(CSV.File("MNIST_data/mnist_train.csv"))
train_X = []
train_y = Int64[]
for row in eachrow(train_data)
    row = convert(Array, row)
    row = [i/255 for i in row]
    X, y = process(row)
    push!(train_X, X)
    push!(train_y, y)
end
train_y = Flux.onehotbatch(train_y, 0:9)
train = [(cat(float.(train_X[i])..., dims=4), train_y[:, i]) for i in partition(1:size(train_data)[1], 1000)] |> gpu
test_data = DataFrame(CSV.File("MNIST_data/mnist_train.csv"))
test_X = []
test_y = Int64[]
for row in eachrow(test_data)
    row = convert(Array, row)
    row = [i/255 for i in row]
    X, y = process(row)
    push!(test_X, X)
    push!(test_y, y)
end
test_y = Flux.onehotbatch(test_y, 0:9)
println("Pre-processing Complete")

m = Chain(
    Conv((5, 5), 1=>16, relu),
    MaxPool((2, 2)),
    Conv((5, 5), 16=>8, relu),
    MaxPool((2, 2)),
    Flux.flatten,
    Dense(200, 100),
    Dense(100, 10),
    Flux.softmax
) |> gpu
loss(x, y) = Flux.Losses.crossentropy(m(x), y) |> gpu
opt = Momentum(0.01) |> gpu
println("Model Creation Complete")

println()
epochs = 10
for i in 1:epochs
    for j in train
        gs = gradient(params(m)) do
            l = loss(j...)
        end
        update!(opt, params(m), gs)
    end
    @show accuracy(test_X, test_y)
end

println()
@show accuracy(test_X, test_y)
```

When I check values of test_X, test_y, train_X, and train_y, they are all in the appropriate format, but I get this error when I try to run the code:

```
┌ Warning: Slow fallback implementation invoked for conv!  You probably don't want this; check your datatypes.
│   yT = Float64
│   T1 = Gray{Float64}
│   T2 = Float32
└ @ NNlib /Users/satvikd/.julia/packages/NNlib/PI8Xh/src/conv.jl:206
┌ Warning: Slow fallback implementation invoked for conv!  You probably don't want this; check your datatypes.
│   yT = Float64
│   T1 = Float64
│   T2 = Float32
└ @ NNlib /Users/satvikd/.julia/packages/NNlib/PI8Xh/src/conv.jl:206
DimensionMismatch("A has dimensions (100,200) but B has dimensions (128,1000)")
```

The stack trace refers to line 55, the one with the gradient.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you need to check your types, since one of them is float32 while other are float64. Typically flux defaults to using Float32, since that's plenty of precision for Deep learning tasks. You could use Flux.f64/f32 as well.

Comment: To solve this problem for me, I just had to do `float32.(x)` where `x` is my image.